# Store two values from JSON_file in new dictionary with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to store two values from JSON_file in new dict like this : `{[1,2,5]:[0], [1,2,4]:[2]}`

my JSON-file looks like this :

```
{
    "index": [
        {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-17 17:56:25",
            "src": "src",
            "dst": [1,2,5],
            "value": [0],
            "datatype": "datatype"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": "2018-04-17 18:00:43",
            "src": "src",
            "dst": [1,2,4],
            "value": [2],
            "datatype": "datatype"
        }
   ]
}
```

I wrote this code:

```
with open(filename) as feedjson:
    json_data = json.load(feedjson)
    feedjson.close()

list_dev = {}
for i in json_data["index"]:
    key = i['value']
    value = i['dst']
    list_dev[key] = value
print(list_dev)
```

I get this **error:**

```
list_dev.update({key: value})
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

can someone help me to fix this problem please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675296/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)

Comment: i saw this solution before. It doesn't help me to fix my problem. Thanks

Comment: Well the error you're having is easily fixable by converting the value variable into something immutable. This is the answer on both, original question and yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is a `list` -> `[1]` or `[2]` or whatever, list is mutable object so you can't hash it

you can use the element in the list like 
`key=i['value'][0]`
or convert the list to tuple like 
`key=tuple(i['value'])`
both objects are immutable thus can be hashed and used as a key

by the way `with` provide context manager so you don't need to close the file using `feedjson.close()`, `with` will do it for you

Comment: Thank your for the answer. key=i['value'][0] i cant use this because i have a long JSON file.When I convert list to tuple key=tuple(i['value']) i get this error:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @AhmyOhlin what are the different types of data that can appear under `value` field?

Comment: Value can be just integers

Comment: I fixed it by converting value to data of type  "string"
value = str(i['value'])
    key = str(i['dst']).
Modify your answer from tuple to string please.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Your example shows Value being a list, not an integer. The immutable version of a list is a tuple. I see nothing wrong with his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just for understanding purposes:

Dictionary keys *should* be *immutable* as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217647/why-must-dictionary-keys-be-immutable). In the question, `[1,2,5]` is a list which are *mutable*(contents can be modified with methods like append,pop, push) data types. So, the only way to use the entire contents of a list as a dictionary key(highly unusual) is to convert it to an immutable data type such as a `tuple` or `string`:

```
new_dict = {}              #initialize empty dictionary

dst = t['index'][0]['dst']      #[1,2,5]
value = t['index'][0]['value']  #[0]

new_dict[tuple(dst)] = value  #new_dict key "dst" as tuple

print(new_dict)     
--->{(1, 2, 5): [0]}

new_dict[str(dst)] = value  #new_dict key "dst" as string

print(new_dict)      
---->{'[1, 2, 5]': [0]}
```