# Immutability of dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, immutability

```
dic={}
dic[1]=100
dic[2]=200
dic[1]+=500
```

here I have initialed a dictionary and I am able to update the key value of the dictionary. But keys in dictionary are immutable, so what's actually happening , can someone please tell?

Comment: You are not modifying the key, you are modifying the value of a key.

Comment: You can find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217647/why-must-dictionary-keys-be-immutable

Answer (score 0):

Just think of it this way. We have an empty dictionary:

```
d = {}
```

If we do this:

```
d[1] = 100
```

we are simply adding a key and assigning a value to that key, right then and there.

---

Just like sets, dicts cannot have duplicate keys, so adding another key with the same name will overwrite the original.

Like doing calling `d[1] = 200` will overwrite the original `d[1]`.

`d[1] += 500` is the same as:

```
d[1] = d[1]+500
```

where we are simply telling python to add a key to `d` called `1`, and assign the value of the original key plus 500 to that key.