# Convert a list of dictionaries to single dictionary with only selected items

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as follows. a,b,c & d values are keys in each individual dictionaries with in the list

```
I = [{'a':'S1','b':'S2','c':'S3','d':'S4'},{'a':'S5','b':'S6','c':'S7','d':'S8'}]
```

Now I need to generate a new single dictionary.
In that keys are 'a' value & 'b' value.
Value for the dictionary is 'd' value.
Sample output as follows. Key can be a tuple or a list.

```
O = {('S1','S2'):'S4',('S5','S6'):'S8'}
```

Can someone suggest me a method.

Comment: Keys _can't_ be lists because dict keys _[must be immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217647/why-must-dictionary-keys-be-immutable)!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use list comprehension as:

```
I = [{'a':'S1','b':'S2','c':'S3','d':'S4'},{'a':'S5','b':'S6','c':'S7','d':'S8'}]

res = { (elt['a'], elt['b']) : elt['d'] for elt in I }
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{('S1', 'S2'): 'S4', ('S5', 'S6'): 'S8'}
```

Update: using for loop

```
I = [{'a':'S1','b':'S2','c':'S3','d':'S4'},{'a':'S5','b':'S6','c':'S7','d':'S8'}]

res = dict()
for elt in I:
    res[(elt['a'], elt['b'])] = elt['d']
print(res)
```

Comment: Hi,,do you know how to use it in append function within a for loop

Comment: Added the code with loop. It doesn't need append() which is for list.