# Item assignment to tuples

Tags: python

I am trying to change the value of a particular element of a tuple of tuples. Here is the code:

```
y=((2,2),(3,3))
y[1][1]=999
print('y: ',y)

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

I understand that `Tuples are immutable objects. “Immutable” means you cannot change the values inside a tuple. You can only remove them.` I was wondering if there is a workaround? I cannot create a list of lists for `y` because I am using `y` as a key in a dictionary later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List vs tuple, when to use each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708510/list-vs-tuple-when-to-use-each)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I mean I understand the difference between lists and tuples. But I am wondering if there is a data structure that can be used for assignment and also be hashed in dictionaries. A tuple does not allow assignment but can be hashed. On the other hand, lists allow assignment but cannot be hashed. So is there a way to do both?

Comment: Do you expect the modified value of `y` to refer to the same entry in the dictionary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217647/why-must-dictionary-keys-be-immutable

Comment: @Nick Thanks, no, the modified value of `y` would refer to a different key in the dictionary.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to _modify_ y instead of just assigning it a new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't expect the modified value of `y` to point to the same dictionary entry, you could convert to a list of lists, modify that and then convert back to tuples. For example:

```py
d = { ((2,2),(3,3)) : 'old', ((2, 2), (3, 999)) : 'new' }
y = ((2,2),(3,3))
print(d[y])
z = list(list(a) for a in y)
z[1][1] = 999
y = tuple(tuple(a) for a in z)
print(d[y])
```

Output:

```
old
new
```

Answer (score 1):

The workaround would be to convert it to the list, make changes, and then convert to the tuple again, if you need to use the tuple later as a key to a dictionary. There is no way to directly change the values.

```
y=((2,2),(3,3))
y = list(y)
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = list(y[i])

y[1][1] = 999

for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = tuple(y[i])
y = tuple(y)

print('y: ',y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the values of tuples because they are constant. But, you can convert it back to a list to be changed.

Code:

```
x=((2,2),(3,3))
y = list(x)
print(y)
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = list(x[i])
y[1][1]=999
print(y)
```